# Por qué el switch se salta un case con acento en php?

Tags: php

Lo que hace la aplicación es al introducir una cadena de texto, la devuelva cifrada y decir sus vocales y consonantes. El problema, es que mi switch no valida vocales con acentos y las omite. Quisiera saber por qué ocurre esto, aquí el switch.

```
$numeroDeFrases= 5;

$frases = array(
    'Al que madruga... Dios lo ayuda.',
    'No por madrugar... Amanece temprano.',
    'Más sabe el diablo por viejo, que por diablo.',
    '¿Cómo estás? ¡Probemos [los] (simbolo) de! puntuación',
    'áéíóú',

);





for($i=0;$i<$numeroDeFrases;$i++){
    $vocales= 0;
    $consonantes= 0;
    $frase[] = $frases[$i];

    for($j=0;$j < strlen($frases[$i]);$j++){

        //Vocales

        switch($frases[$i][$j]){

            case 'A':  
            case 'a':
            case 'á':
             
            case 'E':
            case 'e':
            case 'é':
            
                
            case 'I':
            case 'i':
            case 'í':
            

            case 'O':
            case 'o':
            case 'ó':
           

                
            case 'U':
            case 'u':
            case 'ú':
            
                
                $vocales++;
                $frase[$i][$j] = '*';
                break;

                default:
                
                //Consonantes

                if((ord($frases[$i][$j]) >= 65 && ord($frases[$i][$j]) <=90) 
              || ord($frases[$i][$j]) >= 97 && ord($frases[$i][$j]) <= 122){

                    $consonantes++;
                    $frase[$i][$j] = '*';

                }

               // Para otros caracteres                 

                else{
                    $frase[$i][$j] = $frases[$i][$j];
                }
                break;
                
                
        }
        
    }

    echo 'Frase completa: ' . $frases[$i] . '<br>';
    echo 'Frase cifrada: ' . $frase[$i] . '<br>';
    echo 'Vocales: ' . $vocales. '<br>';
    echo 'Consonantes: ' . $consonantes. '<br>';
    
}
```

Output:

```
Frase completa: Al que madruga... Dios lo ayuda.
Frase cifrada: ** *** *******... **** ** *****.
Vocales: 12
Consonantes: 11
Frase completa: No por madrugar... Amanece temprano.
Frase cifrada: ** *** ********... ******* ********.
Vocales: 12
Consonantes: 16
Frase completa: Más sabe el diablo por viejo, que por diablo.
Frase cifrada: *á* **** ** ****** *** *****, *** *** ******.
Vocales: 16
Consonantes: 18
Frase completa: ¿Cómo estás? ¡Probemos [los] (simbolo) de! puntuación
Frase cifrada: ¿*ó** ***á*? ¡******** [***] (*******) **! ********ó*
Vocales: 14
Consonantes: 22
Frase completa: áéíóú
Frase cifrada: áéíóú
Vocales: 0
Consonantes: 0
```

Como pueden observar, todo funciona relativamente bien, pero el switch no valida las vocales con acentos. Realmente puedo cambiar el switch por if y ya estaría solucionado, solo me interesa saber por qué el switch no valida esas vocales. Ya he intentado validar con la función ord y preg_match pero no funcionó.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Para poder ayudarte es necesario que proveas un [mcve]. Decir que tu sentencia `switch` *está dentro de dos ciclos for* no es suficiente. Saludos

Comment: Tiene razón, ya modifico y explico mejor.

Comment: Debes agregar el código completo

Comment: Ya modifique y agregue todo el código

Comment: El caracter `á` realmente esta compuesto por dos caracteres (multibyte), cuando evalúas `$frases[$i][$j]` sólo comparas el primero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es probable que las palabras con tilde se estén convirtiendo en algún simbolo extraño.

Lo que hice fue hacer un split y recorrerlo, pero con la función mb_split, para que no tenga problemas con caracteres con tildes y en vez de usar el switch hice un array con las vocales y con la función in_array comprueba si existe esa letra dentro del array de vocales.

Ejemplo:

```
<?php

$frases = [
    'Al que madruga... Dios lo ayuda.',
    'No por madrugar... Amanece temprano.',
    'Más sabe el diablo por viejo, que por diablo.',
    '¿Cómo estás? ¡Probemos [los] (simbolo) de! puntuación',
    'áéíóú'
];

$numeroDeFrases = count($frases);

$vocales = [
    'A', 'a', 'á',
    'E', 'e', 'é',
    'I', 'i', 'í',
    'O', 'o', 'ó',
    'U', 'u', 'ú'
];

foreach ($frases as $frase) {
    
    $fraseSeparada = mb_str_split($frase);

    $textoConAstericos = '';
    $contadorDevocales = 0;
    $contadorConsonantes = 0;

    foreach ($fraseSeparada as $letra) {

        if (in_array($letra, $vocales)) {
            ++$contadorDevocales;
            $textoConAstericos .= '*';
        } else {

            //Consonantes
            if ((ord($letra) >= 65 && ord($letra) <= 90)
                || ord($letra) >= 97 && ord($letra) <= 122
            ) {
                ++$contadorConsonantes;
                $textoConAstericos .= '*';
            }else { // Para otros caracteres    
                $textoConAstericos .= $letra;
            }
        }
    }

    echo 'Frase completa: ' . $frase . '<br>';
    echo 'Frase cifrada: ' . $textoConAstericos . '<br>';
    echo 'Vocales: ' . $contadorDevocales . '<br>';
    echo 'Consonantes: ' . $contadorConsonantes . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda bro